# Nginx reverse Proxy url rewrite

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, camunda

I am deploying Camunda in a Docker container behind a Nginx reverse Proxy. When I visit the Camunda landing page on `localhost/app` the page is stuck loading and I get the following logs in the proxy:

```
172.24.0.1 - - [28/Apr/2020:12:14:49 +0000] "GET /app/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.92 Safari/537.36" "-"

172.24.0.1 - - [28/Apr/2020:12:14:50 +0000] "GET /app/welcome/default/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3631 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.92 Safari/537.36" "-"

2020/04/28 12:14:50 [error] 26#26: *2 open() "/etc/nginx/html/lib/require.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.24.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /lib/require.js HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/app/welcome/default/"

172.24.0.1 - - [28/Apr/2020:12:14:50 +0000] "GET /lib/require.js HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://localhost/app/welcome/default/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.92 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

The `require.js` file it's looking for is stored in `camunda/lib/require.js`.I tried rewriting both urls that create the problem in the nginx config like this:

```
location = /camunda/lib/require.js {
        rewrite ^/lib/require.js?$ break;
        rewrite ^/etc/nginx/html/lib/require.js?$ break;
}
```

However it did not work. I am new to rewriting urls, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: your location and rewrite is wrong, comment it and try to access the URL curl://myapp.com/lib/requite.js or curl://myapp.com/camunda/lib/requite.js and put the logs here

Comment: From the error message, the URL is `/lib/require.js`, and Nginx is currently looking for it on your file system at `/etc/nginx/html/lib/require.js`. You don't need to rewrite the URL, you need to set the correct `root` value, so Nginx looks for the files in the correct directory on your file system.

Comment: I changed the root in the camunda container to bypass the welcome screen. Is there a way to tell Nginx to interpret the root of the container somewhere else? Or do I have to change the root of the container back to the default one?